# Type mismatch-problems in java card/deck-classes

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to solve the playing cards-exercises in the Oracle-Java tutorial:

```
public class CardClass {
    public static String suit;
    public static String rank;
    final String[] suits = {"cloves","hearts","spades","diamonds"};
    final String[] ranks = {"Ace","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","Jack","Queen","King"};

    public CardClass(int suit, int rank) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        CardClass.suit = suits[suit];
        CardClass.rank = ranks[rank];
    }

    public static void printCard() {
        System.out.println("The card's suit is: " + suit + " and the card's rank is: " + rank);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CardClass(1,1);
        printCard();
    }
}
```

and

```
public class DeckClass{
    public static String[][] deck;

    public DeckClass() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        for(int i=0; i<4;i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<13; j++)
            deck[i][j]= new CardClass(i,j);
        }
    }

    public static void printDeck() {
        for(String a: deck["hearts"]) {
        System.out.println("In hearts the deck contains:"+ a);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new DeckClass();
        printDeck();
    }
}
```

And I get the following errors:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from CardClass to String in
>       deck[i][j]= new CardClass(i,j);
>
> Type mismatch: Cannot convert from String to int in 
>       for(String a: deck["hearts"]) {

What to do? I am pretty a newbie at this and only could think of choosing a certain suit to print out the cards in the two-dimensional array, so i chose hearts.

Comment: Errors are self-explanatory. if deck in DeckClass is of type String[][], you can't set the reference to a CardClass there. Another problem is that deck is an array, so you can't use it like deck["hearts"], you need to use index such as deck[2], or in case of two dimensions : deck[2][2].

Comment: Try changing `public static String[][] deck` to `public static CardClass[][] deck`

Comment: But, after I change the type of deck to CardClass, i can't print it anymore with the printDeck-method. I can't cast it also. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: After changing the two-dimensional array to a single-dimensional array of size 52 and instantiating the CardClass-Class I had a working DeckClass-Class, but in the CardClass-Class I had to add the card "10" and out-comment the printCard-method, because I it was referencing the (now) non-static variables suit and rank in a static way. After tweaking the limits in the DeckClass-constructors' for loops I now have a working DeckClass!

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor for DeckClass you are trying to assign an instance of the CardClass class to an array of String. In order for that code to work, you need to change deck to array of CardClass.

For your printDeck method, you cannot access an index in a primitive array with a String. You must use an int value. For instance to access the 3 of hearts (assuming your constructor is working) I would use:

`final CardClass fourOfHearts = deck[1][3];`

Check out the Array Access section of this doc:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html

Comment: Thanks! Only after I change the type of deck to CardClass, I am unable to print it via the printDeck-method, since it requires a String and I can't cast it. So, now what?

Comment: See last comment to Mr. Mendoza.